# What does "P.U." (in reference to stinkiness) stand for?

Tags: etymology, abbreviations

"What does {holding nose} P.U. mean?" my son asked me tonight. I told him I didn't know, and he laughed and said "It means *stinky*, Mommy!"  Very funny and well said, but it left me wondering.

A search of Wikipedia and Etymology Online came up wanting and my etymological dictionaries are packed in boxes.  What does this abbreviation stand for and why does it mean *stinky*?

Comment: It’s not the letters ‘p’ and ‘u’, it’s a “word” (and may not even have an official spelling like most guttural noises), and I’m fairly sure it’s supposed to be an ‘f’ sound at the beginning, not a ‘p’. That said, I too am having trouble finding an authoritative spelling/definition for it.

Comment: @Synetech Inc.: For what it's worth, I have always heard/said it with a [p] at the beginning and not an [f].

Comment: I always assumed it came from Pepe Le Pew somehow...Which is to say I also pronounce it "P.U."

Comment: Seems there is Punjab, Purdue, Pune and Princeton Universities ;) PS: I have NEVER heard F.U. about smell

Comment: According to my wife, it stands for "Daddy" (as in Daddy did it again) :)

Comment: I can believe that it's not an acronym, but I have a really hard time believing that it's a variant of "Phew!" @Tim My son used to call flatulence "Daddy", so that one gave me a good chuckle.

Comment: I'm delighted folks, as in extremely delighted that the 'upper crust' of the English language still finds flatulence a little funny. @Kit - Thanks for an awesome and entertaining question!

Comment: So far it looks to me like your kid had the best answer.

Comment: It stands for my (first and last) initials, and is the reason I insist on using my middle initial.  Grade school was tough...

Comment: I always figured that was just onomatopoeia for the sound one makes roughly exhaling the bad air involved.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One person's attempt to find an answer seen on [wordwizard.com](http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?p=63421&sid=0c0d4158ac65c453e193bd7ca53bb10d#p63421) came up with two different postulations which are interestingly possible.

> 1) It's a shortened term for puteo, which is Latin for "to stink, be redolent, or smell bad." I actually called a professor of Latin at the University of Florida to verify this one.
>
> 2) It's actually spelled "piu," but is often pronounced as "pee-yew". It's root is the Indo-European word "pu," meaning to rot or decay. A lot of other languages use this root word and have the same general meaning.

Comment: So possibly related to *putrid* and *putrescence*?

Comment: somewhat likely o_o much moreso than pungent ;O

Answer (score 27):

I'm not 100% on this, but I don't think it's actually an abbreviation. It's possibly a way of saying "phew" that has morphed into "pee-you" or "pyoo" over time, as "phew" is often said with emphasis that makes it sound like two distinct syllables (stress on the "yew"):

> "PheeeeeYEW that stinks!"

Or, to put it in another context that might sound more familiar:

> "FeeYEW that was a close one!"

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/phew

> used as an exclamation to express **disgust**, exhaustion, surprise, impatience, relief, etc.

Still, it's just a guess. I wouldn't be surprised if there was another, more accurate source.

Comment: I wonder if "Fee-you" is a regional difference.  I have never heard it pronounced this way in relation to stinkiness, but I have heard it that way in relation to relief after exertion.

Comment: I didn't mean "Fee-you" in relation to P.U., but the way one would pronounce "phew". As in "FeeeeYOU that stinks!". Makes it sound like two syllables, and somewhat like "Pee You". Still, it's just a guess.

Comment: I think "phew" is a way to write a sigh of relief. The non-exaggerated way to write the sound you make in response to a stink is "pew". (The exaggerated way, naturally, is "P.U.")

Answer (score 6):

My boys and I decided that p.u. stood for *positively unpleasant*. Of course, we have no source for this, and it is likely to become a folk etymology now.

Comment: Tee hee! Works for me!